# VBA+Excel. Erro no código (tipo incompatível de argumento Byref) em Função

Tags: vba, excel-vba

**O seguinte código:**

```
Sub segundograu()
Dim a, b, c, delta, raiz1, raiz2 As Double
a = Range("B3").Value
b = Range("E3").Value
c = Range("H3").Value
delta = b ^ 2 - 4 * a * c
Range("E5").Value = delta
If delta >= 0 Then
raiz1 = x1(a, b, c)
Range("C5").Value = x1

End If

End Sub

Function x1(a1 As Double, b1 As Double, c1 As Double) As Double
x1 = (-b + System.Math.Sqr(delta)) / 2 * a
End Function
```

**Retorna este erro**:
 Tipo incompatível de argumento Byref. 
 aqui: raiz1 = x1(a,b,c)

**O que estou fazendo de errado?**

Comment: Fiz apenas a correção no seu código, veja a edição da resposta para notar o código seu original, com pequenas redundâncias que havia deixado intencionalmente para visualizar apenas o que havia de equívocos. Respeitando o ponto de vista de nosso colega danieltakeshi e da comunidade que aprovou a edição, a resposta foi incrementada com refino do código e melhoramento das funções para melhor performar o resultado esperado. Boa sorte e sucesso!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para corrigir esse erro basta usar `ByVal` na declaração das variáveis em sua função, porém existem outros dois pontos que creio que precisar corrigir em seu código, segue correções:

Dim a, b, c, delta, raiz1, raiz2 As Double declara somente raiz2 como Double e as outras como Variant. O correto e melhor é `Dim a as Long, b As Long, ... , n As Long`

```
Sub segundograu()
Dim a As Long, b As Long, c As Long, delta As Long, raiz1 As Long, raiz2 As Long
    a = Range("B3").Value
    b = Range("E3").Value
    c = Range("H3").Value

    delta = b ^ 2 - 4 * a * c
        If delta > 0 Then
            raiz1 = x1(a, b, c)
            raiz2 = x2(a, b, c)
            Range("C5").Value = raiz1
            Range("C6").Value = raiz2
        ElseIf delta = 0 Then
            raiz1 = x1(a, b, c)
            Range("C5").Value = raiz1
            Range("C6").Value = ""
        ElseIf delta < 0 Then
            Range("C5").Value = "delta <0"
        End If
End Sub

' Coloque ByVal antes das variáveis para receber o valor e não a "referência"
Function x1(ByVal a1 As Long, ByVal b1 As Long, ByVal c1 As Long) As Long
    ' Para usar a função Sqr basta uscar "Sqr"
    delta = b1 ^ 2 - 4 * a1 * c1
    x1 = (-b1 + Sqr(delta)) / (2 * a1)
End Function
Function x2(ByVal a2 As Long, ByVal b2 As Long, ByVal c2 As Long) As Long
    delta = b2 ^ 2 - 4 * a2 * c2
    x2 = (-b2 - Sqr(delta)) / (2 * a2)
End Function
```

Espero ter ajudado!